# Android Zoomview center

Tags: android, image, alignment, zooming, center

I tried to create a zoom view with an image that is always scaled about its center. However, if I change the initial position of the image and pinch the image moves to the lower right corner of the window. As a reference I used the pinch zoom view of the Android Developer and changed some parameters. You have any ideas to fix that?

```
package android.oli.com.fitnessapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class ZoomView extends View{

    private Drawable mIcon;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    Context context;

    public ZoomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX - ((mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()) * mScaleFactor) / 2, mPosY - ((mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()) * mScaleFactor) / 2);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mIcon.draw(canvas);
        //rectMid.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
        //canvas.drawRect(rectMid, blue);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    invalidate();
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<android.oli.com.fitnessapp.ZoomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it :D

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class ZoomView extends View{

    private Drawable mIcon;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    Context context;
    int height, width;

    public ZoomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 0 +  mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 + mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(width/2 + mPosX - (mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth() * mScaleFactor) / 2, height/2 + mPosY - (mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth() * mScaleFactor) / 2);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mIcon.draw(canvas);
        //rectMid.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
        //canvas.drawRect(rectMid, blue);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    invalidate();
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```